# HTTP Access to Linux VM in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm banging my head on this seemingly simple task. I'm trying to stand up a Redhat VM in Azure. I've tried both the resource group approach and the classic approach.

I currently have a classic deployment. I've installed httpd via yum. I confirm that I can SSH to the server via the virtual IP. Once in, I start httpd and I can perform `wget http://localhost/` and get the content that I expect.

However, when I attempt to connect to the virtual IP from my local browser, there is no response. I've also tried creating a static public IP with no success.

I have created an HTTP "endpoint" in Azure portal. I set the public and private ports to 80 with a protocol of TCP. There are no ACL values (I assume it's defaulting to allow everything).

There is no network security group assigned to the VM.

Still no success. What else am I missing!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you really setup an endpoint on the portal to allow port 80, the only thing thats left is the firewall on the Linux VM itself, allow port 80 on the firewall and you are good to go

Comment: I would agree. iptables is disabled on my Redhat server. Maybe I'm misconfiguring the endpoint? When I have no ACLs configured, does that default to denying everything? I don't really understand CIDR representation of 0.0.0.0/0 (I understand CIDR blocks, just not all zeros). 

I attempted an ACL "allow" rule for my IP even with a fairly large CIDR block included, still nothing...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints#manage-the-acl-on-an-endpoint; Take a look at that article. Also, 0.0.0.0/0 means every possible IP address

Comment: AH! So apparently iptables isn't used by default on Redhat v7+ - instead, there is a new firewall service called firewalld. I had checked iptables prior to posting this, but I just found out about firewalld. This will open port 80 in the firewall: "firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent" followed by a reload of the service.

Comment: great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

1) service httpd restart and 2) service firewalld restart did the trick